# How to get the version of the given SQL Server Compact Edition database file (.sdf) using OLEDB API?

Tags: c++, sql-server-ce, oledb

My C++ app needs to deal with SSCE database files belonging to different versions. Right now, I have no way of knowing the version of the database.

The problem is that if the version of the OLEDB SSCE provider mismatches the version of the database file, `IDBInitialize::Initialize()` fails with `E_FAIL`. One has to obtain the respesctive `IErrorInfo` object to get a meaningful error message.

The point is that the error code of `E_FAIL` does not tell me whether the failure is because of the version mismatch or for some other reason. In the first case, I should retry with another SSCE provider, while in the second the application should terminate.

How can I implement this logic? Is there some API that I can invoke before calling `IDBInitialize::Initialize()` to check the version compatibility? Is there a way to get the real error code instead of the opaque `E_FAIL`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the first bytes of the file - see this sample in C# - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html